# Extbase remove duplicate objects in controller / repository

Tags: typo3, fluid, extbase

We took over a project from another company and needed to update their TYPO3. We're on the recent 8.7.13 now.

There is a product extension that filters products, groups and projects into one view. Due to unknown reasons, the following outputs 2 products, which are both the same:

```
public function findByObjekt($uid) {
    $query = $this->createQuery();

    $query->matching(
             $query->contains('objekte', $uid),
             $query->equals('objekte.hidden',0),
             $query->equals('objekte.deleted',0)
    );

    $query->getQuerySettings()->setRespectStoragePage(FALSE);
    $query->getQuerySettings()->setRespectSysLanguage(FALSE);
    return $query->execute();
}
```

**Is there any way to remove duplicate entries / objects here before they are returned to the controller for output?** I've checked multiple docs but could not find a way to have unique results (which is probably no need for usually...). Another thought would be to handle the duplicate logic within the fluid template, but that's a rather bad solution, I'd guess.

Comment: Are there products in database table with the same UID? I think `$query->equals('objekte', $uid),`is more specific.

Comment: @HeinzSchilling No, the UID is always unique. And equals can not work because of the relation.

Comment: Is it a multi-lingual website?

Comment: @Martin Yes. English is default, German second. The system is built to grab the default language dataset and use the translation for the output.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have the desired record in the default language and in one localization.
With extbase, the original language record and all its localizations have the same identifier (uid), although they are different in the database. Extbase usually only finds the record with the current language.

As you `setRespectSysLanguage(FALSE)`, extbase will not filter by language. That's why you receive two records.

Why do you set respectSysLanguage to false anyway?

Comment: When I set respectSysLanguage true, a few entries were missing in the translated output, compared to the default language. I don't know why though, they are translated.

Comment: And do you still have duplicates with respectSysLanguage==true?

Comment: No, I don't have duplicates with this setting, but had missing objects. A colleague fixed it now, finally. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Andreas , we are curious: please share with us how your colleague fixed it.